# Codeigniter updating database but not uploading image

Tags: codeigniter, upload

the code below is updating the database but it's not uploading the image, I checked the folder permissions. Thank you in advance. I have update to show the whole function. The whole function is working, it's only the upload that's not working.

```
public function update_company()
{  

    $distributor = $this->aauth->get_user();
    $distributor_id = $distributor->distributor_id;

    $company_name = $this->input->post("company_name");
    $contact_name = $this->input->post("contact_name");
    $number = $this->input->post("number");
    $email = $this->input->post("email");
    $address = $this->input->post("address");

    if(empty($company_name))
    {

        $message = '<p style="color: red;">Please enter the company name!</p> <br />';
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $message);
        redirect('/your_profile/company');
        return;

    }

    else if(empty($contact_name))
    {

        $message = '<p style="color: red;">Please enter the contact name!</p> <br />';
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $message);
        redirect('/your_profile/company');
        return;

    }

    else if(empty($number))
    {

        $message = '<p style="color: red;">Please enter the phone number!</p> <br />';
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $message);
        redirect('/your_profile/company');
        return;

    }

    else if(empty($email))
    {

        $message = '<p style="color: red;">Please enter the email address!</p> <br />';
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $message);
        redirect('/your_profile/company');
        return;

    }

    else if(empty($address))
    {

        $message = '<p style="color: red;">Please enter the address!</p> <br />';
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $message);
        redirect('/your_profile/company');
        return;
    }

    else if (strlen($company_name) < 2)
    {

        $message = '<p style="color: red;">The length of the company name is too short!</p> <br />';
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $message);
        redirect('/your_profile/company');
        return;

    }

    else if (strlen($contact_name) < 2)
    {

        $message = '<p style="color: red;">The length of the contact name is too short!</p> <br />';
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $message);
        redirect('/your_profile/company');
        return;

    }

    else if (strlen($number) < 9)
    {

        $message = '<p style="color: red;">The length of the phone number is too short!</p> <br />';
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $message);
        redirect('/your_profile/company');
        return;

    }

    else if (strlen($address) < 2)
    {

        $message = '<p style="color: red;">The length of the address is too short!</p> <br />';
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $message);
        redirect('/your_profile/company');
        return;

    }

    else
    {   
        $this->load->library('upload');

        if ($_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0) 
        {
            $this->upload->initialize(array( 
               "upload_path" => base_url().'/assets/uploads/distributors/',
               "overwrite" => FALSE,
               "max_filename" => 250,
               "encrypt_name" => TRUE,
               "remove_spaces" => TRUE,
               "allowed_types" => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg|",
               "max_size" => 500,
               "xss_clean" => TRUE,
               "max_width" => 600,
               "max_height" => 150
            ));

            if (!$this->upload->do_upload('picture')) {
                $message = 'Failed to upload the image';
            }

            $data = $this->upload->data();

            $picture = $data['file_name'];
        } 
        else 
        {
            $picture = 'default.jpg';
        }

        $message = '<p style="color: green;">You succesfully updated your company profile</p> <br />';
        $this->customer_model->update_distributor($distributor_id, array(
            "company_name" => $company_name, 
            "contact_name" => $contact_name, 
            "number" => $number,
            "email" => $email,
            "address" => $address,
            "picture" => $picture       
            )
        );

        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $message);
        redirect('/your_profile/company');
    }
}
```

Comment: that code is not updating a database.  nor is it producing an "upload" form....

Comment: @KraangPrime I did load the upload library above that code, and this code has worked for me before. Its a snippet,changing it

Comment: @cfnerd the problem seems to be a codeigniter 2 bug when uploading, I'm still hunting for a working solution, you can check the replies on the 2 Answers, I appreciate the help.

Comment: @Stephen are you uploading mulitiple files at a time?

Answer (score 0):

The image is not uploading due to wrong path...

So

```
 "upload_path" => './assets/uploads/users'
```

Change to

```
 "upload_path" => './assets/uploads/users/'
```

The best way for managing uploading path is make use of `base_url()` by loading `url` helper.

Comment: One would think using a framework would take care of silliness like a missing trailing `/` in path names.

Comment: @HikmatSijapati I uploaded the whole function, only the upload is not working

Answer (score 0):

First your Path is not valid. Try to correct path suggested by @Hikmat Sijapati.
Next you are not checking what actual error is coming. Try to check errors using $this->upload->display_errors() if your file is failing in upload.

Comment: I'm using CI 2, got this error, The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.

Comment: 'file_name' => string 'customer.jpg' (length=12)
  'file_type' => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
  'file_path' => string 'C:/wamp64/www/app/assets/uploads/distributors/' (length=50)
  'full_path' => string 'C:/wamp64/www/app/assets/uploads/distributors/customer.jpg' (length=62)
  'raw_name' => string 'customer' (length=8)
  'orig_name' => string '' (length=0)
  'client_name' => string 'customer.jpg' (length=12)
  'file_ext' => string '.jpg' (length=4)
  'file_size' => int 24793
  'is_image' => boolean true

Comment: seem to be a CI 2 bug

Comment: you are allowing these file types in your code 
"allowed_types" => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg|",
are you uploading any other type file ?

Comment: when I removed that line the code started working, I will do the error handling via js for file types, I'm uploading images only, thanks for your response.